# How to remove footer links in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

Can anyone tell me how to remove footer links?
I edited "default.xml"  in theme folder.
But it did not work fir me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to

`app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/page/html/footer.phtml`

and you will mostly find static block there for links.

Login to admin panel->cms->static block and find your static block and change the links

Hope this will help you please ask if you have any doubuts

Comment: You are always welcome

Comment: Can you do me a favour? Where is the place to edit to remove "My whishlist" and "Log in" icons?

Comment: what ? please ask

Comment: can you show me your website or can you tell me on which page you want to change, or if you want find anywhere then ask a new question

Comment: It is "colourplus.diamonds". It is located in top right of the page.

Comment: I cannot see what you can so I dont know please give me link or provide screenshot

Comment: or check in this file `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/page/html/header.phtml`

Comment: My website is www.colorplus.diamonds

Comment: HI..can you see it?.Thank you already..

Comment: its on the same file I mentioned

Comment: But when I delete tha header.phtml file it does not chabge the icons.

Comment: Dont delete this file It will lead you in truble and if you delete or rename this file then magento pickup next fallback header.phtml file

Answer (score 0):

Check out these link.

http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/remove-footer-links

For company links to remove or edit by default in magento Rwd theme from backend admin panel we get a option of Footer Company links.

```
Inside CMS -> static block -> Footer Company links
```

go to app/design/frontend/[yourpackage]/[yourtheme]/page/html/footer.phtml and remove footer (below company, connect with us block).