# Remove orders and returns from footer

Tags: magento-1.9, footer-links

working in Magento 1.9 
I want to remove the "orders and returns" from the footer

went into the sales.xml file and commented out

```
<!--<reference name="footer_links2">
<block type="sales/guest_links" name="return_link"/>
<action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>return_link</blockName></action>
</reference>-->
```

but now the orders and returns link appears when the user is as a guest and disappears when he is logged in

I also tried to search multiple files for the keyword "orders and return" but in vain.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way to remove element.
you need to create a `local.xml` at

> {MagentoRoot}/app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/layout

With following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links2">
            <remove name="return_link" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Above code will remove **Orders and Returns** link for all customer

Comment: If `<remove name="return_link" />` doesn't work, then try replace it with `<action method="removeLinkBlock"><name>return_link</name></action>`

Answer (score 1):

By default Magento will **only** show that link to guest users.
The code you commented out in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/sales.xml` points to `block type="sales/guest_links”`.
Take a look in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Guest/Links.php` you will see that it first checks if the user **is not**
logged in and only then does it show him the link to “Orders and Returns”

```
class Mage_Sales_Block_Guest_Links extends Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links_Block
{
    /**
     * Set link title, label and url
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->_label = $this->__('Orders and Returns');
            $this->_title = $this->__('Orders and Returns');
            $this->_url = $this->getUrl('sales/guest/form');
        }
    }
}
```

As with **all** config and layout changes in Magento, you **must** flush the cache for the changes to take effect.

So, flush your cache and that link will **never** show up again.

Comment: ah i understand but I pressed on all those flush cache buttons and indexed everything already but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

To change footer links, check these links--

1) [first link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135649/how-to-remove-footer-links-in-magento-1-9&ved=2ahUKEwjt85PGzZveAhWcgUsFHSB8B2gQFjAJegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3bp9dH_5BuNdaRDwKzt4UA&cshid=1540264920103)

2) [second link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135649/how-to-remove-footer-links-in-magento-1-9&ved=2ahUKEwjt85PGzZveAhWcgUsFHSB8B2gQFjAJegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3bp9dH_5BuNdaRDwKzt4UA&cshid=1540264920103)

Let me know if you still have issue .